# Где прописать примечание/описание/комментарий проекта на Android?

Tags: eclipse, android, java

Есть много проектов Android в Eclipse.

Хочу для каждого проекта писать свой отзыв, чтобы в будущем не просматривать проект по новой. Куда его писать?
Мои варианты:

- в `project.properties` - не вариант, т.к. "Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!";
- в `AndroidManifest.xml` - вариант. Можно там сразу под строкой `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`...
- можно создавать отдельный текстовый файлик в каждом проекте ...

Может, кто знает ещё варианты. Возможно, есть какой **грамотный подход** (**поле** специальное для заполнения или **надстройка в Eclipse** специально под это)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делайте, как делает большинство - в корне с проектом создавайте файл с названием readme.txt и пишите туда все, что нужно.
Можно создавать и readme.md - очень хорошо, если собираетесь хранить свой проект на github. Тогда как только проект будет открыт на сайте, но внизу будет Ваше описание.
Также можно создавать файлы типа Install.txt, где описывать особенности установки приложения.

Comment: Спасибо! Про readme.md не слышал.
Нашёл ещё инфы тут: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304863/how-to-write-a-good-readme Может кому пригодится.